# MongoDB quick start fails during setup

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy the mongo db quick start as [seen here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/step2.html).

Unfortunately, it quickly fails with status CREATE_FAILED with the following error which I can't understand a lot from:

```
Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-****** was not successfully created:
The following resource(s) failed to create: 
[NAT1EIP, NAT2EIP, PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation, PrivateSubnet2ARouteTableAssociation, PublicSubnetRoute, PrivateSubnet1ARouteTableAssociation, PublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation].
```

I tried using both my own user's role and a new role I created where the trusted entity was CF and permissions of power user. It failed in both cases.

I'm surely missing something very basic, any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to create these networking resources, it could be very well due to IAM user restrictions.

Comment: It makes sense but I even tried using the root user - it still failed. Could maybe tell me what exactly the role must have in order to let it through?

Comment: If it's failing in for the root user which has max perms, you may be running to a resource allocation issue with the EIP or creating your subnets.  I would also consider Atlas which is on AWS and provides MongoDB as a service.  https://mongodb.com/atlas/

Comment: Spot on! I ran out of Elastic IPs for my account.. Thanks Jay!